# Ios youtube api upload video, how to log error userInfo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm using GoogleAPIClientForREST for Ios, and i'm trying to upload a video to a channel. After i had obtain a token with AppAuth, i try to upload a video file but

```
GTLRYouTubeService *service = self.youTubeService;
    _uploadFileTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                            completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *callbackTicket,
                                                GTLRYouTube_Video *uploadedVideo,
                                                NSError *callbackError) {

                                if (callbackError == nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"uploaded");


                                } else {

                                     NSLog(@"error %@",callbackError.description);
                                }


                            }];
```

returns me this error :

```
HTTPStatus Code=403 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2265 72726f72 73223a5b 7b22646f 6d61696e 223a2267 6c6f6261 6c222c22 72656173 6f6e223a 22696e73 75666669 ..... 74205065 726d6973 73696f6e 227d5d2c 22636f64 65223a34 30332c22 6d657373 61676522 3a22496e 73756666 69636965 6e742050 65726d69 7373696f 6e227d7d>}
```

I know that probably is an auth error, but i wanna know more details, how i can nslog in a human readble format the userInfo dictionary?

EDIT

What i wanna retrive is the "detail" column of the error, docs example:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"error %@", callbackError.localizedDescription);
```

Comment: i have already tried localizedDescription, it returns only (com.google.HTTPStatus error 403.) not the the detail